# Is flushing or landfilling cat litter more environmental friendly?

Tags: cats, toilet-training, cleaning, cat-litter

I've tried to google that one - is it more environment friendly to flush cat litter (assuming it is flushable) or landfill it? I can see that flushing has disadvantage of polluting water, while we throw away to landfill too much things anyway.

If it matters, I'm in California and use (at least for now) World's Best Cat Litter (as they are used to it from shelter).

Comment: Depends on the litter, depends on how your area processes both sewage and solid waste. Ask your local sewer and trash agencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concern in California is protection of the [California Sea Otter](http://seaotterresearch.org/seaotters.shtml). In 2004, some [researchers discovered](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020751904000050) a significant number of dead sea otters on the beach and autopsy revealed that they had died from [toxoplasmosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toxoplasmosis) infection.

It is not known how much of the toxoplasmosis infection comes from house cats (when poop is flushed, the parasite enters the water supply and is not killed by water sanitation methods, so it is eventually flushed out to sea) or from feral cats (who poop on the ground, which is then washed into rivers/streams when it rains), but cat owners are warned not to flush their cat's poop so they do not contribute to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the bottom of this page https://www.worldsbestcatlitter.com/natural-cat-litter/

There is, coincidentally, a little blurb about California "*The state of California encourages the disposal of cat feces in trash and discourages flushing feces in toilets or disposing of them in drains."

The litter you are using is essentially dried up corn with no chemicals added making it safe for the environment - flush or no flush. As to why it's different in California you may have to contact the manufacturer.

Comment: My guess would be either water shortage or the water treatment standards.

Comment: I could also imagine them trying to avoid clogging up drains.